# PRESTO SQL count group by date

Tags: sql, presto

I have a Presto sql table called  "imp_pixel".

Here a record of a table :

```
date_time                ip              impression_id
2022-08-27 07:05:48      192.0.0.1         001
2022-08-27 07:05:58      192.0.0.12        002
```

I would like to show the sum of impression_id group by hour

I tryed with this code

```
select
    date_trunc('hour', CAST(date_time AS date)) date_time,
    COUNT(impression_id,0) AS 'impression_id'
    from parquet_db.imp_pixel
    group by date_trunc('hour', date)
```

But I got this error :

```
line 3:31: mismatched input ''impression_id''. Expecting: <identifier>
```

Can you help me please to fix this error?
thanks

Comment: I suppose you firstly need to double-quote `impression_id`, and then convert the GROUP BY expression exactly same as the one provided within the SELECT list(without the alias `date_time` of course)

Comment: thanks, which impression_id should be quoted ?

Comment: next to `COUNT(impression_id,0) AS`, should be converted from `'impression_id'` to `"impression_id"` or just `impression_id`

Comment: I try this : `select
    date_trunc('month', date_time) AS 'date' ,
    COUNT(impression_id,0) AS "impression_id"
    from parquet_db.imp_pixel`  BUT it does not work

Comment: Btw, using `COUNT(impression_id, 0)` is wrong either, just use as `COUNT(impression_id)` ( So `'date'` is, use it as `date`)

Comment: I try this : `select
    date_trunc('hour', CAST(date_time AS date)) date_time,
    COUNT(impression_id) AS "impression_id"
    from parquet_db.imp_pixel
    GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', CAST(date_time AS date))`  but I got this error : Value cannot be cast to date: 2022-08-28 08:52:33

Comment: seems the data type of `date_time` is not `timestamp`. If so, cast it as timestamp before date conversion such as `DATE( CAST( date_time AS timestamp ) )`

Comment: seems complicated :(     I try this : `select DATE( CAST( date_time AS timestamp ) ), 
COUNT(impression_id) AS "impression_id"

from parquet_db.imp_pixel
where d='2022-07-27' limit 100 `    but still a lot of errore . Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting date_time to date, we lose the hourly data

```
select
date_trunc('hour', CAST(date_time AS timestamp)) date_time,
COUNT(impression_id) AS impression_id
from parquet_db.imp_pixel
group by 1
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but it does not work :  i got this error :   line 2:1: Unexpected parameters (varchar, integer) for function count. Expected: count() , count(T) T

Comment: I have modified the answer;